# Detect when script tags are appended after load

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to detect when script tags are appended to an HTML page *after* the ready and loaded events for the page have already fired?

For example: third party you have no control over waits for jquery `$(window).load()` to fire before appending script tags to the head of the document. I want to know when those scripts are appended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.scripts
```

will tell us all the scripts that you have at the moment. 
If you know what scripts are loaded at the beginning, you can tell the difference between two sets.

Comment: But I'd just have to keep polling that property in order to tell when it's changed, correct? I'd prefer an even that would let me know exactly when to look at that property.

Comment: Tried MutationObserver and Object#watch and could not make it successful to detect property change dynamically. You still can poll by using setInterval function